# composer card import error return "Required file not found: connection.json"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I created the admin card for the business network using below command

> composer network start -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n airlines8 -V 0.0.1 -A Admin -S adminpw

logs

```
Starting business network airlines8 at version 0.0.1

Processing these Network Admins: 
userName: admin

✔ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Successfully created business network card:
Filename: admin@airlines8.card

Command succeeded
```

To import that I run the below command but got an error

> composer card import -f airlines8 -c admin@airlines8

error logs:

```
Error: Required file not found: connection.json
Command failed
```

Comment: You need a connection.json file, if you check fabric samples and maybe fabcar example, you should find it and adapt it to your network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command to import the card is not correct, try

```
composer card import -f admin@airlines8.card
```

The `-f` flag defines the name of the card file you want to import.